# How to create array with this in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have list in html text arealike this.

```
12345
23456
12345
78938
85768
```

my question, how to get the list and create new array with list format..?

sorry about my english

Comment: You mean you want an array like this? array(123456, 23456, 12345, 78938, 85768); ?

Comment: I have list in text area in html, the format list like in my question.and i want to get the list and create array in php

Comment: [] - bracket syntax is only available starting in PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery : Get textarea value and replace new line with comma

```
var txtval = $.trim($("#txtareaid").val()).replace(/\r?\n/g, ',');
```

// PASS jQuery variable to PHP

PHP: explode() function to convert string into an array based on comma

```
$a = txtval;
print_r(explode(',', $a));
```

Comment: succes full with this answer very thnks sir...!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean, exactly, but I am assuming you have a list of numbers, separated by line breaks. In that case, you can do this:

```
explode("\n", $the_string);
```

If you need to strip out carriage returns (like on Windows), do this:

```
explode("\n", preg_replace("/\r/", "", $the_string));
```

Comment: .this is i mine. Thanks sir. i will tray it and back again

Answer (score 0):

First You want to Create Array Then,
Use it
$arr1 = array("12345","23456","12345");
echo "I want need".$arr1[0]."";

Answer (score 0):

Say you submit the form to 1.php

### code(1.php)

```
$text=$_REQUEST['t1'];
$arr=explode("\n", trim($text));//$arr is the array of all the entries in the textarea with name 't1'
```